# Find minimum weighted spanning tree in Neo4j graph

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, minimum-spanning-tree

I have drawn a graph in neo4j which have following nodes:

- Driver
- School
- Students

Which have following conditions:

- A driver is connected to all students by 'connects' relationship with 'distance' as attribute
- Each Student is connected to each other by same 'connects' relationship with same 'distance' attribute
- Each Student is also connected on one School by same 'connects' relationship with same 'distance' attribute

Now I want to get the minimum path that driver will cover to reach to school with N number students. For that, I am using neo4j predefined procedures(Algorithms):

```
MATCH (n:Driver{name:"Driver2"}),(s:student),(sc:school),(n)-[c:connects]->
(s),(s)-[d:connects]->(sc) CALL 
algo.spanningTree.minimum('students','connects','distance',ID(n)) YIELD 
loadMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, effectiveNodeCount
RETURN loadMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, effectiveNodeCount
```

which gives result like this:

```
[
{
"keys": [
  "loadMillis",
  "computeMillis",
  "writeMillis",
  "effectiveNodeCount"
],
"length": 4,
"_fields": [
  {
    "low": 5,
    "high": 0
  },
  {
    "low": 1,
    "high": 0
  },
  {
    "low": 0,
    "high": 0
  },
  {
    "low": 1,
    "high": 0
  }
],
"_fieldLookup": {
  "loadMillis": 0,
  "computeMillis": 1,
  "writeMillis": 2,
  "effectiveNodeCount": 3
}
},
{
"keys": [
  "loadMillis",
  "computeMillis",
  "writeMillis",
  "effectiveNodeCount"
 ],
"length": 4,
"_fields": [
  {
    "low": 5,
    "high": 0
  },
  {
    "low": 0,
    "high": 0
  },
  {
    "low": 0,
    "high": 0
  },
  {
    "low": 1,
    "high": 0
  }
],
"_fieldLookup": {
  "loadMillis": 0,
  "computeMillis": 1,
  "writeMillis": 2,
  "effectiveNodeCount": 3
 }
},
{
"keys": [
  "loadMillis",
  "computeMillis",
  "writeMillis",
  "effectiveNodeCount"
],
"length": 4,
"_fields": [
  {
    "low": 4,
    "high": 0
  },
  {
    "low": 0,
    "high": 0
  },
  {
    "low": 0,
    "high": 0
  },
  {
    "low": 1,
    "high": 0
  }
 ],
 "_fieldLookup": {
  "loadMillis": 0,
  "computeMillis": 1,
  "writeMillis": 2,
  "effectiveNodeCount": 3
 }
},
{
"keys": [
  "loadMillis",
  "computeMillis",
  "writeMillis",
  "effectiveNodeCount"
],
"length": 4,
"_fields": [
  {
    "low": 4,
    "high": 0
  },
  {
    "low": 0,
    "high": 0
  },
  {
    "low": 0,
    "high": 0
  },
  {
    "low": 1,
    "high": 0
  }
],
"_fieldLookup": {
  "loadMillis": 0,
  "computeMillis": 1,
  "writeMillis": 2,
  "effectiveNodeCount": 3
}
}
]
```

MY QUESTION IS: How to interpret this data? and if it not the right way then which Neo4j procedure(algo) should i use?

Comment: This is not a Spanning tree problem. You want the shortest route for the driver? right? This is the TSP not MST!

Comment: My bad, It is TSP. Do you have any solution?

Comment: The problem is it will take quite some time especially when you are having couple of students, because its NP hard. But you can do a shortest path search for all nodes to all other nodes and brute force all permutation. Neo4j is currently not having such a procedure. I already requested this feature for small amounts.